# Centering in Atlassian Confluence

Tags: confluence

Is it possible to center some things in Atlassian Confluence 3.5.17??

Like in HTML `<center> Headline </center>`
And in Confluence i want to centering

```
{navmap:mainframe\|wrapAfter=4\|cellWidth=200\|cellHeight=50}
```

I can't find it.

Comment: Probably if you post which is your actual problem with "centering some thinks" (I understand centring something) and a little bit of code if needed would be easier to help you (if there is the tag here, someone should know something about it).

Comment: Is it better like this ?

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you are trying here, but it seems someone did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the "Section Macro" is what you need, you can then divide up a page into columns etc.

```
{section:border=true}
{column:width=100px}
This is the content of *column 1*.
{column}
{column}
This is the content of *column 2*.
{column}
{section}
```

Comment: thanks that what i mean when i get the right px than it is in the middle !

Answer (score 0):

I was a little bit blind.. i search and search and search..
but the answer is you can centering thinks with:

```
 {center} {center}
```

Sorry for this silly question !

Comment: There is also the [{align}](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/AtlassianConfluence/align+macro) macro. Or [{float}](http://www.adaptavist.com/display/AtlassianConfluence/float+macro).